# Margin of collapsed navbar-text in Bootstrap 3.3.5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <span class="navbar-brand"><img width=20 height=20 src="{% static 'images/mmlogo.png' %}"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><p class="navbar-text">Ты не вошел</p></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

But when my browser's screen's width is small (like mobile phone) and Bootstrap collapses some elements, I get this:

[image: Wrong]

There's no margin/padding. But when I change `<li><p class="navbar-text">Ты не вошел</p></li>` to `<li><a href="#">Ты не вошел</a></p></li>`, everything is OK:

[image: Right]

But I don't need a link, I just need unclickable text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is due to the default properties of bootstrap

Comment: You need to write your own css to replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have CSS you should post it. If you don't have any CSS related to the text then it is just using default styling from bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<li><div class="col-lg-12"><p class="navbar-text">Ты не вошел</p></div></li>
```